# Invalid character in header content [\"0\"]

Tags: node.js, axios, retry-axios

I am looking to implement a retry mechanism using `retry-axios`. I have successfully installed the package in the node project.

```
const baseUrl = `https://mock.codes/500`
const myAxiosInstance = axios.create();
        myAxiosInstance.defaults.raxConfig = {
            retry: 5,
            retryDelay: 5000,
            backoffType: 'static',
            instance:myAxiosInstance,
            onRetryAttempt: err => {
                const cfg = rax.getConfig(err);
                console.log(`Retry attempt #${cfg.currentRetryAttempt}`);
            }
        };
        const interceptorId = rax.attach(myAxiosInstance);
        const res = await myAxiosInstance.get(`${baseUrl}`);
```

The retry operation has been attempted only once. afterward, I got `Invalid character in header content [\"0\"]` error.

I need to start retrying the operation if the response is 500 or 400.

Thanks is advance

Comment: This is an [Axios bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5089). Nothing anyone here can do about it other than suggest you use an older version, eg v0.27.2

Comment: @Phil Thank you. Issue resolved by downgrading the Axios version to 0.27.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Phil mentioned in his comment, this is a bug with Axios itself. It is known to affect Axios [1.1.0](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5055) and [1.1.2](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5089) at the very least. It was affecting me in 1.1.3 as well.

The fix is here but has not yet been approved. https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5090

Commenters in the github issues suggested downgrading Axios to pre-1.0.0. I am no longer experiencing this issue after switching to:

- axios 0.27.2
- axios-retry 3.3.1

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Issue resolved by downgrading the Axios version to 0.27.2

Answer (score 0):

Since the above answer is highlighting the bug in the axios package itself, I recommend to manually resolving the issue as followed:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const baseUrl = `https://mock.codes/500`
let retryCount = 0;                                            // Track the count of requests with retry count.

async function test() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}`);             // Make request
        console.log(res);                                      // Log the successful response
    } catch(err) {
        if(err.response.status !== 200 && retryCount < 10) {   //  Check if the response code is not equal to 200, log and retry
            console.log(`Retrying ${retryCount} time......`);
            retryCount += 1;
            await test();
        } else {
            console.log(`Retry count exceeded 10 times.`);     // Log the maximum retry count, to avoid an infinite loop
        }
    }
}
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Appstronaut Studios said above,

axios version 1.3.2 just came out 2 days ago and that seems to fixed the issue as well. https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v1.3.2